# Which visa is required to move to the UK as a US citizen married to a UK citizen with our child born in the US?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, citizenship, uk-citizens

My fiance is a UK citizen. I want to move there with my daughter. We are both US citizens. I understand I will need to apply for a join partner visa, which I need to apply for our daughter. Her father is a UK citizen and she is a US citizen. We plan to stay permanently. I want to apply for the right visas, so that we have fewer problems in the long run and make this as easy as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Is your daughter a minor?

Comment: As your daughter is the daughter of a UK citizen, she is very likely also a UK citizen (that is, a dual citizen), in which case she should not apply for a visa, but a passport.  If her UK-citizen father was born in the UK, for example, she is already a UK citizen.

Comment: Yes she is a minor only 11 months old, but she was born a US citizen, but yes her dad is a born UK citizen.  Just a situation we were gonna get married first but got a surprised baby in the mix as well before we had chance for me to move to him and get married.  He came for her birth he is on her birth certificate and everything.  My fiance said she isn't a UK citizen because she wasn't born there, so please explain how she is a UK citizen when she's never been there.  He has only been here.

Comment: Your fiance is a British citizen "not by descent" since he was born in the UK. Therefore, your daughter is a British citizen, see this link for more info: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen/y/on-or-after-1-january-1983/no/yes (the "you" on that page refers to your daughter). So, she has dual citizenship and needs to apply for a UK passport (instead of a visa) to live in the UK. You still need a visa, of course, and I'll let people who know more about that answer that part of your question.

Comment: Can you clarify if your fiance is the father of your daughter. Also, would you be willing to get married in the US prior to moving to the UK?

Comment: Welcome to Expats.SE. Please take a look at our [help]. You should probably search around, but if you do not find a question about children and UK citizenship, please ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Yeah my fiance is the father of our daughter, and yes he plans to come here and for us to get married.  Before I apply for my visa.  Which in that case if she does qualify for a British passport, do I need to mention her on my visa for coming over with me.  Because I know that adds to the visa cost for each dependent.

Comment: @Autumn: If there's a space on the visa form for "dependents travelling with you" or something like that, then yes you would mention your daughter. But there will be no extra cost for just mentioning her, since she is a UK citizen and does not need her own visa.

Answer (score 1):

You stated in the comments that you plan to get married before applying for the visa, so you should apply for a [family visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa) as a spouse for yourself, after you are married.

You also stated in the comments that your British fiance was born in the UK, and that he is the father of your daughter. This means that your daughter is a British citizen, and you should [apply online for a British passport](https://www.gov.uk/apply-renew-passport) for your daughter, not a visa. Your daughter has right of abode in the UK, so I don't think she counts as a dependent for your spouse visa application fee, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The passport application link is not for first-time applicants.

Comment: @phoog works for me? Answer no to the have you had a UK passport before question.

Comment: I think I misread "you can apply for, renew, replace or update your passport" as "you can apply to renew, replace or update your passport."